# How do I start making cement on my own?

Tags: cement

I want to make my own cement because its the most costly one for building house. How do I approach for making my own cement?

Comment: Manufacturing cement is pretty simple. But it's not cheap and typically involves things like strip mining and industrial furnaces. It's not a DIY project.

Comment: Strip mining? That's a bit of hyperbole. Quarrying limestone or collecting seashells. Burning it is a bit of a process, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you have to mix lime and sand. If you want concrete you add rocks.

So you will need to find a source of lime, limestone will work. The ancient Romans used volcanic ash.

Powderize the limestone and cook the heck out of it, like burn it. You will need a furnace that gets to like 2000°F. Then mix it with a bit of water and some sand.

Probably cheaper to buy it my man.

Answer (score 0):

[Try some these](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=cement%20recipes) Otherwise, I'd stick to getting concrete trucks of wet or dry mixes to your request. A 9-yard truck around me is $1200 & worth every single penny as I would never try to mix even just 1 truck's load by hand & it wouldn't ever be cost effective.

I know you guys have them too, but I don't know what they cost.